# how to obtain all values of a multi-valued key from Django's request.GET QueryDict

Tags: django

The Django docs say at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.iteritems that`QueryDict.iteritems()` uses the same last-value logic as `QueryDict.__getitem__()`, which means that if the key has more than one value, `__getitem__()` returns the last value.

Let's say `print request.GET` looks like this:

`<QueryDict: {u'sex': [u'1'], u'status': [u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4']}>`

If I want to get a string like `sex=1&status=1&status=2&status=3&status=4` (standard HTTP GET stuff) the following code won't give the desired results because of the `iteritems` behavior mentioned above:

```
mstring = []
for gk, gv in request.GET.iteritems():
    mstring.append("%s=%s" % (gk, gv))
print "&".join(mstring)
```

What is the most efficient way to obtain the result that I want without too much looping?

Regards.

[EDIT]

I should mention that I am not resorting to `QueryDict.urlencode()` because there are some keys in that request.GET that I don't want in the string. I could alter the string and take those key=value out, but just wondering if there is a better way to go about this. I realize this information should have been explicitly mentioned.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work:

```
mstring = []
for key in request.GET.iterkeys():  # "for key in request.GET" works too.
    # Add filtering logic here.
    valuelist = request.GET.getlist(key)
    mstring.extend(['%s=%s' % (key, val) for val in valuelist])
print '&'.join(mstring)
```

Comment: There is a `request.GET.iterlists()`. Also I think that approach by David's answer below is cleaner.

Comment: @Ski: Agreed. That's why I upvoted it :-) Still, doesn't help if you want to filter out a subset of keys before encoding.

Answer (score 26):

```
request.META['QUERY_STRING']
```

will give the complete query string

or if you want to get the list of values for a given key 
ex: list of values for status then

```
request.GET.getlist('status')
```

Answer (score 8):

I believe QueryDict.urlencode achieves your desired outcome if all you want to do is print out the QueryDict then just

```
print request.GET.urlencode()
```

should do the trick. Let me know if you were trying to do something else and I'll try to help!

Comment: Yes, that does the job. But what I haven't mentioned in the original post (that I should have) is that there are some keys in request.GET that I don't want in the string. I could search the string and take them out, but wondering if there is some other way. I will edit and re-phrase my question.

Comment: `data = request.GET.copy()`, then remove stuff from data you don't need, and then do `data.urlencode()`.

Answer (score 8):

```
request.GET.getlist('status')
```

Answer (score 4):

It's easy!
Just `print(dict(request.GET))`

Answer (score 2):

To obtain all the values from one. It's better to use `getlist("key", default=list)`. All the values from the key is stored in a list.

```
request.POST.getlist('key',default=list)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can cast the querydict into a dictionary

```
map(int,dict(request.GET)["status"])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful function in django http utils you can use:

```
>>> from django.utils.http import urlencode
>>> print(urlencode({"tag": [1, 2, 3], "sentence":2}, doseq=True))

'tag=1&tag=2&tag=3&sentence=2'
```