# How to create your own filter like django admin site

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to create the same filter in the django admin site (please see photo) for the users. Which is the best way to do it?
[image: admin site filter]

Comment: Please show some code. Your `models` and your `admin` please.

Comment: hey nik i did not even start to write any code I hoped that i can somehow include it

Comment: Of course there is a way but without code how SO can help you?

Comment: So I guess I cant include the code from the admin site!

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research I found this application: https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter

Answer (score 0):

It is just a queryset. You can add similar form to your template with `<form method="GET">` and then in your will just parse that items like `request.GET.get('key', None)` or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3324009/3042057) for iteration of all request parameters.

There are few plugins that helps you to do that. Check some of them [here](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/filters/). Django-filters for example has template structure and etc. which will help a lot.